# C# CurlSharp EasyGet - How to get string result

Tags: c#, curl, get, libcurl

I'm using this code to make an EasyGet request.Does anyone know how to get a string result?

```
using CurlSharp;
public static void CurlSharpGet(string url, bool useHttp2 = true)
    {
        Curl.GlobalInit(CurlInitFlag.All);

        try
        {
            if (useHttp2)
            {
                using (var easy = new CurlEasy())
                {
                    easy.Url = url;
                    easy.WriteFunction = OnWriteData;
                    easy.HttpVersion = CurlHttpVersion.Http2_0;
                    easy.SslVerifyPeer = false;
                    easy.SslVerifyhost = false;
                    easy.Perform();
                    Console.WriteLine(easy.Perform());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (var easy = new CurlEasy())
                {
                    easy.Url = url;
                    easy.WriteFunction = OnWriteData;
                    easy.Perform();
                    Console.WriteLine(easy.Perform());
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Curl.GlobalCleanup();
        }
    }

    public static Int32 OnWriteData(byte[] buf, Int32 size, Int32 nmemb, object data)
    {
        Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf));
        return size * nmemb;
    }
```

Ideally i would like to have something that looks like this:

```
public static string CurlSharpGet(string url, bool useHttp2 = true)
    {
        //my fixed code here
    }
```

The nature of what I'm doing cannot be accomplished using httpclient or webresponse. Would appreciate any advice on what I should do to get the above code to return a string result. Thanks

Comment: Do you simply want to return what's currently written out to Console in `CurlSharpGet`?

Comment: No, I should have left out that Console line, I had it in there for debugging. I'm looking for the actual string result from the request. thanks